# what is the best way to use rest api and parse data, jackson or groovy in android?

Tags: android, json, rest, groovy, gson

hey I want to download data and parse it in a `textview`. Which one should I use? If I am correct `groovy` does not use a model class but `jackson` does similar to `Gson`. A model class improves understanding. So what should I use? please shed some light on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience at it comes two library GSON or Jackson

It’s upto you how you consider particular library is the best, whether it’s in terms of achieving performance, code optimization or optimizing UI or something else.

In terms of reduction of lines of code, both the libraries are good, I mean you can reduce boilerplate code using either of these library.

In terms of performance, Jackson gives better performance and does quick parsing, one gentleman has done comparison of JSON Parsers, do check it!

[image]

Comment: You can try with the module which is bundled with Groovy: groovy-json, which has a pretty fast JSON parser. See http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Use can use Retrofit library for this, if you want to make RESTful webservoce call.

Retrofit is a library that will let you define your API in a simple Java interface and will automatically convert it into a full-blown REST client. it uses models for parsing JSON data using Gson. If you want more information on what you can do with Retrofit, you can check out their website ([Retrofit Website](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)), but for now let's just assume it's an awesome library and jump start to using it.

Comment: you mean use retrofit for making a the httpgetrequest and then use either jackson or gson for parsing?

Comment: You dont need to parse the response seperately. It automatically parse the response according to the models your have defined and fields defined in that model. Please checkout their documentation : http://square.github.io/retrofit/.